# How to fix "Undefined ReadFile"

Tags: go

I am going to use [ReadFile](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile):

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
   ReadFile("data.txt")
}

>> undefined: ReadFile
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Qualify it with the package name:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    ioutil.ReadFile("data.txt")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, but I already have package name.  I have updated my question.

Comment: You're missing the package name on the `ReadFile` call.  `ioutil.ReadFile("data.txt")` vs `ReadFile("data.txt")`